# Schur-Cohn Stability Test.

Tags: stability

Where can I find a proof for the Schur-Cohn stability test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reference is: Proakis J.G., Manolakis D.G., “Digital Signal Processing”, Prentice Hall, 1996.

Comment: Thanks Jorg! 

I found another document, which I suppose gives an easier proof as compared to going through the Proakis's bulky chapter on Lattice Filters to figure it out. 

http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/9780470611104.app6/pdf

